# Error: Use instance member on type

Tags: ios, swift, function-calls

In the below code, I have an "instance member on type" error when I am trying to call the `matchTravellerWithLocal` function and assign the return value to message. Any idea on how to solve this error?

```
var travellerInformation: Traveller{
    return Traveller(destination: location, travellingPreference: preference)
}

let message = matchTravellerWithLocal(travellerInformation)



func matchTravellerWithLocal(traveller: Traveller) -> String {
    var message = ""
    let location =  traveller.destination.rawValue
    let type = traveller.travellingPreference.rawValue
    let locals = LocalsInformation().locals
    for (name, information) in locals{
        let city = information["City"]
        let preference = information["Preference"]
        if city == location{
            message = "Meet your local: \(name), a local of \(city)"
            print(message)
        }else{
            message = "Apologies, there aren't in \(city) on LocalRetreat. Try again soon!"
            break
        }
        if preference == type{
            message += "who is also a \(preference)"
            print(message)
        }
    }
    return message
}
```

Comment: You message variable is a type variable (defined outside of any function)  but you are assigning the result of calling `matchTravellerWithLocal` an instance function. That function needs to be called on an instance of whatever class this is, or it needs to be defined as a class function

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out - I created a computed variable, and it works.         var message: String {
        return matchTravellerWithLocal(travellerInformation)
    }